# Referring to values in the outer SELECT within the inner SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing this tutorial -http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial - and question 6 is  Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:  I've got the answer correct, but how i can get the same answer without using SELECT within inner SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the largest country (by area) in each continent without using a select within an inner select.  YOU CAN if you only need to get the Continent and MAX area but since you also need the country name, then you cannot.

However, if this is an alternative solution.

```
SELECT continent, name, area
FROM world 
where (continent, area) in (select continent, max(area) from world group by continent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
from your_table
where isnull(gdp,0) > (
    select max(isnull(gdp,0))
    from your_table
    where continent='europe')
```